# How to pass passwords trough api gateway securely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function to signup users into a cognito userpool. I want to fusionate lambda with api gateway to make easier.

What is the safest way to send password, email and credentials trough api gateway?